# Function not declared in this scope

Tags: c

I dont know how to declare this function.

> Error:
>                          In function 'int main(int, char**).
>   line 25  colume 16    [Error] 'histogram' was not declared in this scope

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 99
#define M 99

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a,i,j,count=0;
    char x[N][M];


    for(i=0;i<N;i++) {
        printf("input word,\n input ****end for exit: ");
        scanf("%s", x[i]);
        a=strcmp(x[i], "****end");
        if(a==0) break;
        count++;
    }
    for (i=0;i<count;i++){
        printf("%s\t", x[i]);

    }

    histogram(x);

}

void histogram(char[N][M]){
    int i,j,count;
    char x[N][M];
     for (j=0;j<count;j++){
     for(i=0; i<strlen(x[j]) ;i++)
     printf("*");
     printf("\n");
    }    
}
```

Comment: Why people down vote me? is this silly question?

Comment: You could have solved this problem *if* you had completed a quick google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions need to be declared before they're used in C. Either move the definition of histogram up above main, or add

`void histogram(char[N][M]);`

to the top of the file.

Comment: Cool, don't forget to check it off as accepted too. Also, for future reference, the short thing added to teh top of the file is called the "function prototype"

Answer (score 1):

You will need to define that function before it is used. For larger programs it is usually helpful to have a header file, though not needed for a single function. Just place a

```
void histogram(char[N][M]);
```

at the top of your file before MAIN. If you continue to add things, I suggest using a header file though.