# Multipying two numbers using a function in C

Tags: c, function, multiplication

Here's my program and I am getting syntax errors that I don't understand. 
This is my main that will accept my function data:

```
int main() //main program
{
    float num1, num2, total; 
    printf("Enter first number:  ");
    scanf("%f", &num1);
    printf("Enter Second number:  ");
    scanf("%f", & num2);
    total = multiNumbers(num1, num2);
    printf("sum is %2.f", total);   
    return 0;
}

int multiNumbers(int num1, int num2) {
    int sum;
    sum = num1 * num2;
    return sum;
}
```

Here are the compilation errors:

```
In function 'int main()':
[Error] 'printf' was not declared in this scope
[Error] 'scanf' was not declared in this scope
[Error] 'multiNumbers' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: Is this your whole source-code file? where IS "multiNumbers"?

Comment: i put my function below.. Thats not the lines with the syntax

Comment: You should post the whole code as explained in [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- nevertheless, it seems obvious now

Comment: Side note - you should change all types in `multiNumbers` to `float` instead of `int` if you want to have the correct multiplication result..

Comment: @SGH, nice catch, but then just go for `double` (for a better chance of correct results). `float` is probably the most nonsensical datatype in C on most platforms.

Comment: [Printf was not declared in this scope](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38560419/1441), [Function not declared in this scope](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23327630/1441) (...I could keep going)

Answer (score 3):

> [Error] 'printf' was not declared in this scope
>
> [Error] 'scanf' was not declared in this scope

Add stdio library in your code

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

> [Error] 'multiNumbers' was not declared in this scope

Add a declaration before main function

```
 int multiNumbers(int num1, int num2);
```

Code Snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int multiNumbers(int num1, int num2);
int main() //main program
{
    float num1, num2, total; 
    printf("Enter first number:  ");
    scanf("%f", &num1);
    printf("Enter Second number:  ");
    scanf("%f", & num2);
    total = multiNumbers(num1, num2);
    printf("sum is %2.f", total);   
    return 0;
}
int multiNumbers(int num1, int num2) {
    int sum;
    sum = num1 * num2;
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> [Error] 'printf' was not declared in this scope
>   [Error] 'scanf' was not declared in this scope

`printf` and `scanf` are declared in `stdio.h`, so you need to include this file first:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

> [Error] 'multiNumbers' was not declared in this scope

If this function isn't declared or defined above your main function, you must at least add a declaration like this above main:

```
int multiNumbers(int num1, int num2);
```

(just this line)

Answer (score 1):

You must at least declare the function before you call it.  A function definition also serves as a declaration, so the easiest thing to do is move the body of `multiNumbers` before `main`.

**Edit**

```
int multiNumbers(int num1, int num2) {
  int sum;
  sum = num1 * num2;
  return sum;
}

int main() //main program
{
    float num1, num2, total; 
    printf("Enter first number:  ");
    scanf("%f", &num1);
    printf("Enter Second number:  ");
    scanf("%f", & num2);
    total = multiNumbers(num1, num2);
    printf("sum is %2.f", total);   
    return 0;
}
```

One problem that the compiler *will* complain about - your types don't match.  You've declared `multiNumbers` to take `int` parameters and return an `int` value, but you're passing `float` values and assigning the result to a `float`.

That's not going to work.

If you intend `multiNumbers` to work with `float` values, then you need to change the types of `num1`, `num2`, and `sum` to `float` (although honestly, I'd recommend using `double` instead of `float`).

Answer (score 1):

You must first

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

and you must also put the functions prototype before main().

```
#include <stdio.h> // You forgot this

int multiNumbers(int num1, int num2); // This is the function's prototype

int main() //main program
{
    float num1, num2, total; 
    printf("Enter first number:  ");
    scanf("%f", &num1);
    printf("Enter Second number:  ");
    scanf("%f", &num2);
    total = multiNumbers(num1, num2);
    printf("sum is %2.f", total);   
    return 0;
}

int multiNumbers(int num1, int num2) {
    int sum;
    sum = num1 * num2;
    return sum;
}
```